# Laravel preview before save to DB

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, database-design

I need your advice on what's the best practice for the next problem:

I have a (very sophisticated) form in my admin panel, it saves images, regular fields to the main Model and also saves a lot of relations for the main Model.

Now I want to add a "preview before save" function, so the admin can preview the changes just before saving them to the DB, the problem is that I can't actually save the Model or it's relations to the DB because then the users will see the updated data before it's published. 
I also can't unpublish the post or any of it relations because the users wont have access to the post.

Update:

It's important to know that the solution has to be generic, since I can't always know what are the Models and Objects that the preview page uses.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What information needs to be previewed exactly?

Comment: All the site (as usual ) including the changes made to the Main model and its relations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to browse the site with the changes in effect then you'll have to work in a way to identify a post and its related models as being in some sort of "draft" mode which is only visible to specific users.

You can set up query scopes for eloquent for example that can automatically filter queries for any model by a certain column/value:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#query-scopes

I'd create a query scope that does an auth check and adds a where clause in to filter results down if the user isn't logged in (you could optionally check for a specific role here too):

```
class PublicScope implements ScopeInterface {

    public function apply( Builder $builder )
    {
        if( !Auth::check() ) {
            $builder->where(function( $query ) {
                $query->where('is_draft', '!=', 1);
            });
        }
    }

    public function remove( Builder $builder )
    {
        $query = $builder->getQuery();

        foreach((array)$query->wheres as $key => $where) {
            if($where['column'] == 'is_draft') {
                unset($query->wheres[$key]);
                $query->wheres = array_values($query->wheres);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want the models with updates to be hidden away while they're being previewed you could generate duplicates of each model in draft mode so the old models remained untouched. If the user decides to ditch the changes you could just delete the duplicated models, if they want to proceed and save them it could overwrite the old ones.

Comment: So your advice is to save the relations in the same tables or clone also the tables ?

Comment: Same tables, perhaps append (Draft) to the post name. Use query scopes to ensure drafts are only seen by administrators system wide without needing to add a where clause to each query manually.

Comment: I'd probably look into creating a trait for any models that can have drafts that listens for a "saving" or "updating" event, checks the draft status and modifies the behaviour accordingly. That way you don't have to make modifications to your controllers/commands/jobs and mess around with form input.

Comment: And what about a case when the user didn't discarded the changes from the drafts?

Comment: Then the draft would just stay there until someone deleted it, just have it show up in the list of posts with a draft status and allow them to go back in to finish editing it or delete it all together.